# How to run an application by clicking on hyperlink you get in an e-mail in your mail client?

Tags: c#, .net

Client wants to be able to open application and appropriate form (function) by clicking 
in the e-mail's hyperlink.

For instance, you send an e-mail to someone with the link to the application's function where the issue is described.

The receiver clicks on it, the app is launched and the appropriate form is displayed.

how can this be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a custom URL protocol handler: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/10/19/register-a-custom-url-protocol-handler.aspx

For example look at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http` or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp` to get an idea of how to do it.

The `shell\open\command` key has a default value which contains the executable to run when the URL protocol is triggered.